# Python: How to loop through a dictionary mutiple times?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key, key-value

I want to create a code that has a dictionary that can print out different types of outcomes. I have two dictionaries. One of them have different sets of outcomes and the other dictionary values are empty strings which is where I want the values to be stored in and printed multiple times with different sets of outcomes. Also wanted to know if it was possible if can create another loop where it has only the first letter printed in each key in a dictionary. Here is my code so far.

```
a_dict = {'A': [['LA', 'Sallys', 'Associate '], ['Hollywood', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'],['Compton', 'Sally', 'Shelves']],'B': [['SAC', 'Sallys', 'Associate '], ['Townsland', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'], ['Compton', 'Tiffanys', 'Shelves']]}

b_dict = {'Site':"", 'Store':"", 'Station':""}

        for key in a_dict:

       

        b_dict.update(a_dict) 

        print(b_dict[key])

        #print(b_dict[key[0]])
```

I want the output to be like this

'Site':"LA", 'Store':"Sallys", 'Station':"Associate"

'Site':"Hollywood", 'Store':"Tonys", 'Station':"Shelf"

'Site':"Compton", 'Store':"Sally", 'Station':"Shelves"

And also like this

'Site':"L", 'Store':"S", 'Station':"A"

'Site':"H", 'Store':"T", 'Station':"S"

'Site':"C", 'Store':"S", 'Station':"S"

Answer (score 0):

```
output = [
{'Site':val[0], 'Store':val[1], 'Station':val{3]}
for vals in a_dict.values()
for val in vals
]
```

This will give you the list of b_dicts you require

Answer (score 0):

So you have this `a_dict` with keys `A` and `B` that seem to be what you call "outcomes", and the values are a list of "sites" with data for the site name, store and station.  Right?

```
a_dict = {
  'A': [
           ['LA', 'Sallys', 'Associate'], 
           ['Hollywood', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'],
           ['Compton', 'Sally', 'Shelves']
       ],
  'B': [
           ['SAC', 'Sallys', 'Associate '], 
           ['Townsland', 'Tonys', 'Shelf'], 
           ['Compton', 'Tiffanys', 'Shelves']
       ]
 }
```

The keys of your `b_dict` are:

```
b_keys = ["Site", "Store", "Station"]
```

You could create the `b_dict` on the fly using `zip`, if printing it is all you need:

```
for key, sites in a_dict.items():
    # print(key)
    for b_values in sites:
        print(dict(zip(b_keys, b_values)))
```

But if you need to do something else later, you could easily give it a name with `b_dict = dict(zip(b_keys, b_values))`